# Injectivity of $x^3+x \bmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $$f_n:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, x \mapsto x^3+x \bmod n$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now if $f$ is not injective i.e. there exist $a\neq b \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $$a^3+a=b^3+b \bmod n \qquad \text{or} \qquad (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+1)=0 \bmod n$$
then $f_{kn}$ is also not injective for any integer $k$. How can you show it?

Comment: Have you actually tried any examples?  Try $n=5$.

Comment: Not sure what I will see. $f_5$ is not injective and I haven't found a $k$ for which $f_{5k}$ is injective.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?  You say "apparently it is true."   Apparently *what* is true?   I, and the user who posted below, assumed you were trying to show that $f(x)$ was injective.  But why make your readers guess?

Comment: @lulu I think the proposition is clearly stated: "If $f_n$ is not injective, then $f_{kn}$ is also not injective"

Comment: Thanks @AnilCh that's what I need :-)

Comment: The way this question is worded may throw people off. Your first sentence:"I'm not sure how to see it but apparently is true" may get the reader to assume that you think this statement is true and that you are looking for either a proof or a counterexample. That was what I first thought reading this question.

Comment: @Mike. I deleted it if it really worries people -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3+x$. With respect to each and every modulus $n>1$ it gives rise to a function $f_n:\Bbb{Z}_n\to\Bbb{Z}_n$. If $P(n)$ is the predicate: "$f_n$ is not injective", then the question is about proving the implication:
$$P(n)\implies P(kn)\ \text{for all integers $k>1$}.$$

So we assume $P(n)$. In other words, there exist integers $a$ and $b$, $0\le a<b<n$, such that $f(a)\equiv f(b)\pmod n$. Let $m$ be the common remainder modulo $n$.

Let $k>1$. Consider the $2k$ inputs $a_i=a+in$, $b_i=b+in$, $i=0,1,\ldots, k-1$. For all $i$ we have
$$
f(a_i)\equiv f(a)\equiv m\pmod n
$$
as well as
$$f(b_i)\equiv f(b)\equiv m\pmod n.$$

It follows that modulo $kn$ all the outputs $f(a_i), f(b_i)$, $i=0,1,\ldots,k-1$, are among the numbers $m_j=m+jn$, $j=0,1,\ldots,k-1$. This is because any integer congruent to $m$ modulo $n$ is congruent to exactly one of the $m_j$s modulo $kn$.

That is, we have $2k$ pigeons $f(a_i), f(b_i)$, flying into $k$ pigeonholes $m_j$.
By the pigeonhole principle at least two pigeons fly into the same hole. In other words $f_{kn}$ is not injective either.

Comment: It is hopefully clear that the conclusion is true for every polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, not just this cubic $f(x)=x^3+x$. It will not surprise me at all if we locate a suitable general duplicate target. I could not find one, but I don't frequent [tag:elementary-number-theory], so I may not know the optimal buzzwords. This is, perhaps, not the most typical exercise, but still...

Comment: Well thanks. This is what I was looking for. It is indeed true for any polynomial since $$f(a+in)=\sum_{l=0}^N c_l (a+in)^l=\sum_{l=0}^N c_l a^l + jn$$ where $c_l$ are integers and $j$ is also some integer. The first term is by the assumption of the form $m+hn$ for some integer $h$ and hence $f(a+in)=m+(h+j)n$. $h+j \in \{0,1,...,k-1\}$ when taking modulo $kn$.